# Eclipse CDT auto format C program

Tags: c, eclipse, format, eclipse-cdt

When I write C program code like this:

```
if ((input = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
```

After use auto format ctrl+shift+F, the code turns into below, with "an extra space" after keyword NULL:

```
if ((input = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL )
```

Would someone please help to figure out a solution? Thanks!

This issue is not related to Formatter -> Edit -> White space -> check "Before closing parenthesis". This extra space was added only after keyword NULL. Suppose I write:

```
if ((input = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == 0)
```

There will be no extra space added after 0, even if I use auto format ctrl+shift+F.

Comment: This was an issue of Eclipse Juno. The issue is solved in Eclipse Luna! Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be adjuster in the formatter that you are using in Eclipse:

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter.
2. Click on Edit.
3. Click on "White Space" tab.
4. Go to Control Statements -> 'if else'
5. Uncheck "Before closing parenthesis"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if i right you want to modify the settings of the formatter of eclipse, so you just go to

**Window**>**preferences**

and in the left panel find the:

C/C++>>Code Style>>Formatter

Now you click to edit the profile.

Go to the tab **White spaces** and find the **Control statement**>>**'if else'**, now only modify the checkBoxes and you can redefine that as you like.